About windows activation
My windows 2016 license is allow 16 device, but now after a clone it cant activate. Even deactivate old device which no longer use, even try phone activate is fail. Totally only use 6 device for now. but how to activate it for the rest. it say exceed limit.
i try slmgr /ato, /upk, /ipk, slui 4.

You need to call the vendor. This forum doesn't handle weird proprietary license stuff.

Is it a 16 core license? If so that's not 16 devices, It's a single device with up to 16 cores.

Not 16 core. cause it bundle with mssql and mssql allow (2), so should not be the 2 is 2 core for mssql. There is a screenshot, but i dont know how to post here, it show grants 16 license.
